# Change color of cell with double click for a specific range only- VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a sheet in which I would like to be able to change the color of a specific range of cells by double clicking on the cell of interest. I only want this to be applied to 3 cells for the entire sheet with the rest not having this capability. I have found the following code online, however, it is not range specific and applies to the whole sheet. Is there a way for me to do this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Case 3: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
    Case 45: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes - which 3 cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Intersect` to check if `Target` falls within `C46:C48`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C46:C48")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Interior.ColorIndex
            Case xlNone, 4: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case 3: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            Case 45: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            Case Else: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```